# Can I write this SQL using Criteria API?

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to reproduce this query in Criteria API. In my mappings I have a many to many between Tag and Product, but this only appears in my Tag class, i.e. the Product class has no knowledge of tags. Basically I want to find all the products that have all of a list of tags. Here is the sql I produced although it is probably possible to improve.

```
SELECT Product.* FROM Product

    WHERE Product.ProductID IN (
        SELECT ProductID FROM ProductTagMap
            INNER JOIN Tag ON ProductTagMap.TagId = Tag.TagId
                WHERE Tag.UrlName = 'sticks')

    AND Product.ProductID IN (
        SELECT ProductId FROM ProductTagMap
            INNER JOIN Tag ON ProductTagMap.TagId = Tag.TagId
                WHERE Tag.UrlName = 'vic-firth')
```

Any Ideas, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're probably best looking at DetachedCriteria's. It's not exactly what you're doing, but [this blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/12/23/NHiberante-Querying-Many-To-Many-associations-using-the-Criteria-API.aspx) has some good examples of using the DetachedCriteria - just replace his Exists with an In instead.

Comment: Thanks, took my simple mind a while to figure it out but the link certainly helped